# Sum cells from another row based on a cell value

Tags: google-sheets

My code is:

```
(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-(I4:I- 1);COLUMN()-4;4)&":"
&ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-4;4)))*( ( J4:J ) / 10 ))))
```

Basically I want to sum cells from Gx - Gy but the range is determined by cell I4. The code above works, but only for one line. I want it tod work for an entire column where the data is.

```
=ArrayFormula( if( J4:J = "" ; "" ;
```

So I put ArrayFormula in front and calculation is shown only where the data is, but the result is always = to result of first row??

Can anyone tell me why this happens, and what to do about it?

My sheet: -> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkKaHeBdxneDdHNNQUY5elliWnZRcEVEdkZpZ2h4S1E&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Thank to TOM HORWOOD, who answered my question:

> With the magic of matrix multiplication and this solution (credit
>   where credit is due), I have managed to wrangle it to do what you
>   want.
>
> =ArrayFormula(IF( J4:J = "" ; "" ; MMULT((ROW(G4:G)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(G3:G)))*((ROW(G4:G)+1-I4:I)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(G3:G)));G3:G)*
>   ( ( J4:J ) / 10 ) )) My head hurts already, so I won't go into too
>   much explanatory detail, except to say that the key magic happens in
>
> ="MMULT((ROW(Range1)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(Range2)))*((ROW(Range1)+1-I4:I)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(Range2)));Range2)))"
>   And I've added a second sheet to your public one with a rough equation
>   builder, for understanding or alternative applications.

Thank you Tom!!